# IEEE membership for academic and professional career

Tags: ieee

I am currently studying for a master's and I will continue my academic career to post-doctorate. I am involved in the research projects of my organization and I will continue my research and development on my organization as well. Now I want to make the IEEE membership account where I can access related research papers for research and development.

> Which type of IEEE account is suitable for both an academic and professional career as in my case?
> Can a student account also be used in professional research and development?

Comment: You should check out IEEE site: https://www.ieee.org/membership/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Student membership is for students only. Once you lose that status, then you will require a professional membership.

Student members have access to the [IEEE digital library](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/home.jsp) through the library of their institution. Professional members have access also, but it requires fees, perhaps a subscription.

But one can gain access if the employer holds an Institutional Subscription to the library.

This is similar to the ACM which has its own digital library, available on similar terms.

But, otherwise, a student membership has most of the advantages of a professional membership but at a lower cost while you remain a student. There isn't really a distinction between Academic and "Professional" membership.

Comment: There are probably certain things a student can’t do (mostly involving voting?) but I can’t see why that’s matter enough not to take the cheaper membership for as long as one is eligible....